# Open an image (jpg, gif, xbm) in binary mode

Tags: html, c, image, client, readfile

I'm working on a server/client assignment. My server should pass down to Client HTML, .txt, .jpg, .gif, and .xbm files to open up on a web browser when I go the localhost:8080/some address... my HTML and .txt files open like a charm! however the .jpg and .gif wont display at all. the server does locate the file but when it comes to reading or displaying the .jpg or .gif it cannot be display because it contains errors, but when I open it in a regular browser it works good. Our instructions are "When you open an image file for reading, make sure to open it in binary mode, since an image file contains binary data." so I did just that but since the image is not displaying I wonder if I'm doing it correctly. Here is my code in c to read a file that I use for html, txt, and image formats.

```
void file_read(char *filename){
    //filename is actually the path
size_in = strlen(filename);
    //this is test display to see how the path was being read and since getting a 
    //from a web browser contains an extra character '/' in the beginning we need to 
    //to ignore it, 
printf("printf in file_read function %d\n", size_in);
wtg = filename + 1;
printf("printf in file_read function %s\n", wtg);

//file open and transfer in binary 'rb'
    fp= fopen (wtg, "rb");
    if (fp == NULL){
        printf("Could not open the file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    fseek(fp , 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell (fp);
    rewind (fp);
    //allocate memory to contain the whole file:
    linehtml = calloc(1, len + 1);
    if (linehtml == NULL){fputs("Memory Error", stderr); 
    exit(2);}
    //copy the file into the buffer:
    if(1!=fread(linehtml, len, 1, fp)){
        fputs("entire read fails",stderr),exit(1);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    /*if (result != len) {
        printf("file lenght is %d\n\n", len);
        fputs ("Reading Error",stderr);
        exit(3);
    };*/
}
```

Is there something wrong? is the buffer not long enough? any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you tag this question with 'c' as well, seeing as that's the language you're working in.  This code does nothing once it has read the file in - how does it get transmitted to the client app? What about the client code - how does that read the data ?  Your mechanism of reading 1 record of (file-length) size in is unusual, and could cause problems if you encounter a large file.

Comment: I did not correctly understand what you may be trying to do. but while returning to a browser, if you want a file data as is, you should set the content-type. just like you set `response.setContentType("text/html")` for html, you should set `response.setContentType("image/jpeg")` os some such for an image.

Comment: can you post the function which sends the file?

Comment: Yes, the code you have here doesn't seem to contain errors, so the problem must be elsewhere. How are the global variables defined? Is, for instance, `len` large enough to hold the size of the image file? When outputting, you are not using string routines, are you? Images can contain zeroes.